# Is it possible for a server to provide the same file to 2 people, on who understands only UTF-8 and the other, only ISO8559?

Tags: wordpress, csv, utf-8, character-encoding

INTRO:
I'm in a situation because when uploading an inventory upload feed to Amazon, in 2021, they still don't understand UTF-8 encoding.

1. Here we have a file, in a wordpress installation, as the image for a visual product.
   Example url : [https://wordpresssite.com/uploads/Café-à-la-crème.jpg](https://wordpresssite.com/uploads/Caf%C3%A9-%C3%A0-la-cr%C3%A8me.jpg)
2. Wordpress displays it fine.
   Amazon reads a bunch of gibberish and can't find the file and gives an error.
3. Can we leave the file name on the source server as is and yet do something in cPanel or in
   the excel file that lists this URL in a way that Amazon can also read it?

Is this ultimately as simple as telling Excel to encode that column differently before uploading?

Thank you in advance!

UPDATE : What I am trying now, is to export the Excel to CSV and then run it through line by line using PHP with a combination of tricks hoping to do a passable job of it. From what I see, there are many ways that "sorta" work, but nothing is sure.

UPDATE 2 : I realize that this doesn't solve my problem, because if Amazon changes the file name, changing an "é" to an "e", then it won't find the image either, so I'll have to go through all the images and find the ones with accents that I'm using.

QUESTION ABOUT PROCEDURE : I haven't been able to quite understand the way things work.  I thought originally that this is about trying to get help when stuck.  I have explained the problem and code isn't necessary. If I'm wrong, please tell me how it changes THIS situation?  I'm using Excel, WordPress and I have to lose the UTF-8 accented characters that seem to cause Amazon's systems such grief (no judgement to Amazon, except that this resistance to UTF-8 is giving me brain shudders at the moment).

MORE INFO: If this helps, I'm writing in English but certain art products have a lot of French and some German in their names. I thought my example sufficient to illustrate what I was up against.

My problem is not how to convert the code but how to put the steps together to do what I need.  It's because this whole process is not a simple iconv vs utf_decode() in php that it's extra stressful.  Once I get the big picture sorted, the smaller steps are written about in many places where I could find more specifc details if I needed.

I'm not snarking here, but it seems that this kind of comment is just kicking someone when they are down.  You are not the first to make such a suggestion over the years but again, I am curious how I could have explained any more than I have already — in a way that pertains to my actual problem.

Thanks for your response.

Comment: What I am trying now, is to export the Excel to CSV and then run it through line by line using PHP with a combination of tricks hoping to do a passable job of it.  From what I see, there are many ways that "sorta" work.

Comment: [1] As it stands your question is vague and hypothetical. It contains no code, and does not even state what language(s) you are using. Can you update it to show what you actually did, and the specific issue that  arose? [2] See [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for further clarification. [3] Your comment is a step in the right direction, but the question itself should be updated with that information, along with the relevant code. It should not be necessary to read any comments to properly understand a question.

Comment: You might also consider rephrasing your dubious claim that _"Amazon, in 2021, ...still don't understand UTF-8 encoding"_ to something more precise and less volatile.

Comment: File encoding doesn't matter (a file doesn't contain information about encoding). You should check your client and server settings: you should tell the other server about the encoding of your file. On your server: are you sure you deliver the correct encoding as the data, and the server headers? [do not look the output: browsers do a lot of things to try to correct errors, but you should not expect this is always consistent or constant]

Comment: CSV is literally just text... it doesn't have a specified text encoding either, you know.

Answer (score 0):

That URI is not properly encoded as per [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) (see also [Wikipedia: percent/URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)). You cannot expect a server to blindly assume a requested URI to be *UTF-8* encoded, but you can expect every server to support percent encoding:
`https://wordpresssite.com/uploads/Caf%C3%A9-%C3%A0-la-cr%C3%A8me.jpg`

In *PHP* this can be achieved thru [`rawurlencode()`](https://www.php.net/rawurlencode); in *JavaScript* it would be [`encodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI).

Not sure what you want with *Excel* and *CSV*, but from what I understood it is unrelated to your actual problem.